# How can I add alpha channel to three channel image using Java OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv

```
String imageName = URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getResource("/BigBlue.bmp").getPath(), "UTF-8");
Mat image = Highgui.imread(imageName);
// How to add alpha channel at, say, 50% and write to PNG?
```

The C++ answer uses mixChannel, but the Java mixChannel API indicates that the source and destination images must be of the same size and depth.

Comment: cvtColor(..., COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

Answer (score 0):

As Miki answered, use cvtColor.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
```

Thanks.